# rename variables in Python code using Python

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I have some Python code as a string,

```py
string = """
import numpy as nmp

y = 5

def f(x):
    return nmp.sum(x) + y

x = 1
print(f(x))
"""
```

Using Python, I would like to rename
the import to `nmp` to `np`,
the function argument `x` to `X` (but not the `x = 1`), and
`y` to `Y`.

To this end, I must be able to identify every usage of the respective variables. I suppose I'd have to use one of [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) or [libcst](https://github.com/Instagram/LibCST), but I'm not really sure.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

The code below traverses the source code as an `ast.AST` object, updating names based on a provided mapping. This mapping lists the new names for the objects to be mutated, and also specifies any scopes in which the replacement should be prohibited:

```
import ast
def walk(tree, mp, scope=['main']):
   for i in tree._fields:
      if not isinstance(a:=getattr(tree, i), list): 
         if a in mp and not {*scope}&{*mp[a]['ignore']}:
            setattr(tree, i, mp[a]['to'])
      n = [a] if not isinstance(a, list) else a
      s = [tree.name] if tree.__class__.__name__.endswith('Def') else scope
      for j in n:
         if isinstance(j, ast.AST):
            walk(j, mp, s)

replace_map = {
   'nmp':{'to':'np', 'ignore':[]},
   'x':{'to':'X', 'ignore':['main']},
   'y':{'to':'Y', 'ignore':[]}
}
string = """
import numpy as nmp

y = 5

def f(x):
   return nmp.sum(x) + y

x = 1
print(f(x))
"""
tree = ast.parse(string)
walk(tree, replace_map)
print(ast.unparse(tree))
```

Output:

```
import numpy as np
Y = 5

def f(X):
    return np.sum(X) + Y
x = 1
print(f(x))
```